# Not able to get the drive items of newly created channel using graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am first creating a channel using graph api and the trying shares/url end point url is encoded, and when I try it I am getting

> Code: accessDenied Message: The sharing link no longer exists, or you
> do not have permission to access it.

Neither I am getting the driveitems by passing the drive id which I get from endpoint teams/teamsid/channels/channel id/filesfolder.

I need to create certain folders immediately on creation of channel

Comment: This is probably just because the artefacts (channels, SharePoint site, etc.) are still being created. What happens if you try access the drive items after, say, 30 seconds or one minute?

Comment: i have waited for almost 5 min, it didnt work

Comment: how to know the sharepoint sites are still being created

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, if you could help on how to know it is still being processed, tried to find out, couldn't find much on it

Comment: It can't still be going, days later, must be something else

Answer (score 0):

When you create a channel, it won't create a files folder in share-point. You need to go to channel and click on files tab to create a files folder in share point. Teams create the files folder in share pint on Demand. This is by design. Could you please try going to channel in UI and redirecting to files tab and then check the folder using Graph API.

for getting driveitems look into following documents:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: What if we want to automat the process